# How to add static labels to jobs in service monitors

Tags: prometheus, servicemonitor

In prometheus we have the option to add a label to every metric of a job with something like this,

```yaml
- job_name: 'your_job'                 
  honor_labels: true                         
  static_configs:                     
  - targets:                          
    - '127.0.0.1'          
    labels:                           
      cluster: 'stage'
```

I want to add labels to metrics but using servicemonitors. I am using blackbox prometheus operator to scan some websites. This is how my service monitor looks.

```yaml
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: prometheus-blackbox-exporter
    app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus-blackbox-exporter
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.20.0
    instance: primary
  name: prometheus-blackbox-exporter-example.com
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  endpoints:
  - interval: 30s
    metricRelabelings:
    - action: replace
      replacement: https://example.com
      sourceLabels:
      - instance
      targetLabel: instance
    - action: replace
      replacement: example.com
      sourceLabels:
      - target
      targetLabel: target
    params:
      module:
      - http_2xx
      target:
      - https://example.com
    path: /probe
    port: http
    scheme: http
    scrapeTimeout: 30s
  jobLabel: prometheus-blackbox-exporter
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - monitoring
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: prometheus-blackbox-exporter
      app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus-blackbox-exporter
```

I want to add a label to the metrics coming from this job. The label is

```bash
project: monitoring
```

How can I do it using servicemonitors?

Answer (score 2):

Add this under `spec.endpoints[].metricRelabelings` or `spec.endpoints[].relabelings`:

```yaml
- targetLabel: project  # name
  replacement: monitoring  # value
```

e.g.:

```yaml
spec:
  endpoints:
  - interval: 30s
    relabelings:
    - targetLabel: project
      replacement: monitoring
```

The option with `spec.endpoints[].relabelings` is better in your case because the label will appear not only on *gathered* metrics but on all automatic (such as `up`) as well.

Read more on relabeling in the docs: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config